# Nested Maven macro variables problem

Tags: variables, maven, macros, properties, nested

In Maven POM I want to implement Resource filter
Consider following property file

1. env=local
2. 
3. local_user=scott
4. remote_user=tiger
5. 
6. database_user=${${env}_user}

Is it possible to have nested maven macros as indicated line no 6

**Regards
 
Rajul Konkar**

Comment: Simply no. If it would be possible it had been been mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply no. If it would be possible it had been been mentioned in the documentation